# Lock rotation of UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation

I have created a view in Xcode 5 with a UIScrollView. I would like to lock the ScrollView so that even if the device is in landscape mode the scrollview stays in portrait. I couldn't see a menu option for this so will I have to do it with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your viewcontroller.m file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

And in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll); //Support all orientations
}
```

Comment: I have just added it and tested it but doesnt seem to change anything the view is still rotating. Should I add it the the super viewDidLoad?

Comment: Edited my answer. No you should add it as a separate method in your viewcontroller.m file not within viewdidload.

Comment: Thanks Nikos Ill test it and let you know :)